# c++ heap pointers weird thing?

Tags: c++, pointers

when I do this

> ```
>    int* pointer = new int;
>    int* pointer2 = new int;
> ```

I suppose these two pointers are next to each other in the memory of my computer ( they are 4 bytes apart) so in theory the two pointers should have a difference of 4 but when I show the pointers it shows this :

> ```
> 0x6000227e0
> 0x600022800
> ```

which is a difference of 2 so that means that int are 2 bytes long?? Is my logic wrong?

Comment: Alignment aside, how these have a difference of `2` actually?

Comment: They have a difference of 0x20 or, in decimal, 32. so there is plenty of "room" inbetween.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's a difference of 32 bytes, not two bytes. The difference is `0x20` in hexadecimal, or 32 in decimal.

Furthermore, you are not even guaranteed that the objects will be allocated consecutively, in memory.

In other words, these memory addresses mean absolutely nothing, whatsoever.